# cannot install any app from windows store for htc 8x

Tags: htc-8x

Whenever i try to download app from windows store an add details pops up with date of birth showing month,day year and country/region but when i click on the drop down menus they remain inactive. Pls what can i do.
have HTC 8x

Answer (score 3):

Log into account.microsoft.com and update your personal information there instead.

Make sure all details are correct.